# Google Truth not allowing us to do .isGreaterThanOrEqualTo() and cannot chain multiple calls

Tags: google-truth

This is using Kotlin in android through tried in a non-android project. It just asks if we want to create the function. The value we wanted to compare was a Double, but `.toInt()` did not help.

FWIW, Bard showed this as possible and when I told it the code was not compiling it said check the import, which is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`isAtLeast(...)`](https://truth.dev/api/latest/com/google/common/truth/ComparableSubject.html#isAtLeast(T))? It's the API that implements a "greater than or equal to" check.

Comment: So strange that Bard does not know that. Or maybe not... thanks!